# What had Zhaan done to be imprisoned?

Tags: farscape

In the first episode of Farscape, Zhaan says the "Even among my people I was something of an anarchist. In fact I was the leading anarchist."

As I recall, this is isn't mentioned again in the series (but I may, of course, have missed it, or forgotten about it; I started watching it the other day, and it's been years since last time).

I'm curious about what the Delvian society was like, considering that the says "Even among my people...", with a bit of emphasis on the word "even". As I understand that, being an anarchist among Delvians was quite an accomplishment. And in light of this, what did she actually do?

I'd prefer an in-universe explanation that I've just missed or forgotten, but things like deleted scenes or interviews with the creators and the crew are definitely acceptable.

At the end of the episode "That old black magic", she also says that before becoming a priest, she was a savage, and while probably not unrelated, I don't get the impression that this is the answer; as I understand it, she was a priest before being imprisoned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Farscape: Rhapsody in Blue](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Zotoh_Zhaan) we learn that Zhaan was imprisoned for a politically motivated murder, that of her mentor Bitaal who had seized power of Delvia in a coup, inviting in the Peacekeepers.

> **Zhaan:** (whispering) *Release your mind Bitaal. Surrender your demons. For I have others replace them.* (and she begins to inflict pain on him)
>
> **Bitaal:** (arching his head back as his hands fall away from her) *What are you doing?*
>
> **Zhaan:** (sobbing) *Avenging the lives you have ruined. The world you put at risk.*
>
> **Bitaal:** (screaming in agony as he dies in her hands) *No! Zhaan! ZHAAAAAAAN!* (Zhaan cries out in grief)
>
> (cut back to the Delvian temple-ship and present reality)
>
> **John:** *What the hell was that?*
>
> **Zhaan:** *The crime I was imprisoned for.*
>
> **John:** (he staggers away from her, horrified) *You - You killed the guy you were having sex with?*